# Can't extend Doctrine's Repository

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to make a custom Doctrine's ORM Repository and extend it but I can't find a way to make it work. So far this is what i have:

The original Repository

```
//AppBundle\Repository\LocaleRepository.php

namespace AppBundle\Repository;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use JMS\DiExtraBundle\Annotation as DI;

class LocaleRepository extends EntityRepository
{

    protected myCustomFunction(){
    }
}
```

The extended Repository

```
//OfficeBundle\Repository\OfficeRepository.php

namespace OfficeBundle\Repository;

use AppBundle\Repository\LocaleRepository;

class OfficeRepository extends LocaleRepository
{
    //Empty class
}
```

My entiy:

```
namespace OfficeBundle\Entity;
// some calls to traits
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Office
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="office__office")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="OfficeBundle\Repository\OfficeRepository")
 */
class Office implements TranslatableInterface{
    //...
}
```

And Finally the call:

```
 $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
 $this->getEntityManager();
 $office=$em->getRepository('OfficeBundle:Office')->myCustomeFunction($slug);
```

This trows the exception:

```
 Undefined method 'myCustomFunction'. The method name must start with either findBy or findOneBy!
```

If I place myCustomeFunction inside the OfficeRepository it works fine but it brings down the purpose of extendind the repository. Also, the repository loaded by the controller is the correct one, vardumping the class shows: 'OfficeBundle\Repository\OfficeRepository'.

Finally I'm using KNP DoctrineBehaviors(translatable) on the office entity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must make your method `public` if you are going to use it outside the repository class.

```
class LocaleRepository extends EntityRepository
{

    public function myCustomFunction()
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it was so obvius... I'm dump